# How do I find the solution set to the inequality $3x^2-4x+5<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I find the solution set to the inequality $3x^2-4x+5\lt 0$?

I know the basic rules for finding the solution set, but I'm not sure what step I should do first to solve the problem, like if I should subtract 5 from both sides first or go straight to factoring.

Comment: I would suggest trying to factor to see if the roots are real. I would not move the five to the other side.

Comment: Try few values of x. Try drawing the plot. Find the real roots/ zero crossings (if any)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the discriminant is negative. So the solutions are complex. That means the graph of the function $f (x)=3x^2-4x+5$ never touches the  $x $-axis. Also since the coefficient of $x^2$ is $3$,a positive integer, the function itself is always positive. (Think of  $x$ tending to large numbers and the domination of  $x^2$ over  $x$.)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if you are willing to help someone out, but do you mind if I send you an email? I really like your explanations. I'm not sure if you are comfortable with giving out that info, but I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MNS213 I think you can receive more help by asking in math.SE rather than other sites (here are more people). Because we <3 math.SE!

Comment: As @manooooh pointed out, it's better to ask your doubts in MSE, rather than to a single person. Here you will receive help from experts. I'm just a noob here. Anyway, if you like my answer, accepting it will be great:)

Comment: The discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac = (-4)^2 - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 16 - 60 = -44$ is a *negative* number, so the roots of the quadratic equation $3x^4 - 4x + 5 = 0$ are complex.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you for pointing out. I'll edit within a minute.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Edited:)

Answer (score 3):

One way is to observe that
$$3x^2-4x+5 < 0 \iff 9x^2-12x+15 < 0.$$
But
$$9x^2-12x+15 = (3x-2)^2 + 11 \ge 11.$$
Therefore, ....

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I think I might be able to solve it! Do you think I could send you an email? I hope you don't mind! I like your explanation.